# Is it possible to create promoted only tweets on behalf of user authorized against tw application?

Tags: twitter

- I have twitter application
- I can authorize users against this application and create tweets on their behalf

I would like to be able to create promoted only tweets via ADS API on authorized users behalf. Is it possible?

So generally, if I have user accessToken & accessTokenSecret (after authorizing him against my app), can I use those tokens to make requests to TW ADS API, for example to list user advertising account ('/accounts' endpoint) and use one of it to create campaign?

Comment: do you have any code which you tried

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

As said in [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/ads/overview/getting-started)

> Like Twitter REST API v1.1, the Advertising API requires the use of both OAuth 1.0A and HTTPS. API keys can be obtained through the application management console. Access tokens must also be used to represent the “current user.” The current user is a Twitter account with advertising capabilities.

but you must have special attention to

> There are two different types of accounts involved in using the Ads
>   API: advertising accounts and Twitter user accounts. Within this
>   documentation, the term “account” refers to the advertising account.
>
> - Advertising accounts are registered on ads.twitter.com and identified in the API by account_id. Advertising accounts link
>     directly to funding sources and leverage content from one or more
>     Twitter user accounts as ‘promotable users’. Each advertising account
>     can grant permission to one or more Twitter user accounts. The
>     advertising account, or “current account,” is represented in nearly
>     every URL executed as an in-line :account_id parameter.
> - Twitter user accounts (such as @AdsAPI) are identified by user_id in the Ads API. One or more of these accounts can be associated with an
>     advertising account. The authenticated Twitter user account making
>     requests on the API is referred to as the ‘current user.’ A listing of
>     advertising accounts that the current user has access to can be found
>     with GET accounts. ‘Promotable users’ are Twitter handles that can be
>     promoted by a specific advertising account. For more details about
>     this, see Obtaining Ads Account Access.